# Excel VBA Loop Activate Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding macros in excel and I am trying to code my spreadsheet to where I have two check boxes in a row hidden until you have inserted text into the B cell of the corresponding row. Once anything is input there, it would "reveal" the hidden check boxes. And to prevent from writing a large number of If statements, I was hoping to create a loop as I have 35 rows that the person can fill up to that have check boxes related to them.

Example

B column is the name.
Once they type a name in row 5, the two checks in row 5 before visible and clickable. 
Then it checks row 6, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unhide a row automatically when you fill in something in a cell, you need to use the [Worksheet_Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) or [Workbook_SheetChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange).

This code triggers when you make a change in a specific sheet. You can put in an if-statement in there to make sure it only continues when the changed range is in column B.